# jQuery - Slider to pull steps from custom "data-steps" attribute

Tags: jquery

I'd like to have all the  items on my page to read their respective step increments from a custom (uneven) "data-steps" attribute, rather than the regular even step pattern.

My HTML markup would then look like this:

```
<div class="options__wrap">
    <div class="options__slider">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="4" step="1" value="1" id="option__slider__item" data-steps="1,2,5,15">
    </div>
    <div class="options__slider__value">
        <span id="options__slider__value__monitor">0</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? In a perfect world, I would like to be able to store the value directly from the  field, but I think I can also settle for reading and storing the final ouput value in "#options__slider__value__monitor".

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hnm7q4k3/7/

Comment: Is it the step or the values that you want to be uneven? In case the latter here is the option: https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-values

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that I only have the base jQuery API to work with. Can't use jQuery UI properties. So I need something that works without the UI API :(

Comment: Can you provide an online example of your code? (e.g. jsbin,codepen..)

Comment: Sure! This is what I have right now: https://jsfiddle.net/hnm7q4k3/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to create a solution based on your example.
The steps are again even, but the code snaps to the correct step on keyup/mouseup.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hnm7q4k3/87/

```
<div class="options__panel">
  <div class="options__wrap">
    <div class="options__slider">
      <input type="range" min="1" max="15" step="1" value="2" id="option-items" data-steps="1,2,5,15">
    </div>
    <div class="options__value">
      <span>0</span> Item(s)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js

```
var $elem = $("#option-items");
var initialValue=$elem.val();
var steps=$elem.data('steps').split(',').map(Number);
var stepsReversed=steps.slice().reverse();
var prevValueDataKey='rng-prev';
var printElem=$(".options__value span");

$elem
.data(prevValueDataKey, initialValue)
.val(initialValue)
.on("mouseup keyup", function(evt){
  var $this = $(this);

  //get previous value
  var prev = new Number($this.data(prevValueDataKey));
  var current = new Number($this.val());

  //calculate the number to snap to
  if(current>prev){
     current = steps.find(function(elem){return elem >=current});
  }else if(current<prev){
     current = stepsReversed.find(function(elem){return elem <=current});
  }

  $this
  .data(prevValueDataKey,current)
  .val(current);

  printElem.text(current);
  console.log("snapped to:",current)
})
.trigger("mouseup");//render the span with the initial value
```

Comment: Thanks! that did the job!